# Excel error when using path name as parameter from command line

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

I am trying to launch a specific Excel document from the command line and pass in a variable in the form of a file path. On starting the Excel sheet runs a macro. This file path may contain spaces however when Excel interprets this it, I believe it tries to open up each section after a space as a new workbook. This results in a number of error warnings after the program runs as it obviously cannot file created from the substring.

The batch file looks like this

```
echo %~1
start excel.exe %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Compare.xlsm /e/%1%
pause
```

EDIT: For Clarification.  The batch file is activate when a file is drag and dropped onto it. The path of the file dropped is then stored in the %1 variable. If this file path has spaces then after each space Excel assumes that this is a new worksheet and tries to open it. The call to the Compare.xlsm which contains a macro that is going to use the path of the dragged file works correctly as it will always be on the desktop. My issue therefore is how to get Excel to take the entire path name stored in %1 and use it as one command line parameter rather than several calls to open new workbooks.

If the file that is used on the batch file does not contain any spaces then the errors do not occur. Is there any way of getting rid of the errors when using a file path that might have spaces e.g. C:\Users\My Documents\foobar.txt

Comment: This has been covered many times in the past :) You have to pad the spaces within Quotes. Do a search on StackOverflow and you will find many posts

Comment: @Siddharth, I had looked on SO but maybe I am not understanding the fixes. The only question that I can find relating to mine does not have an answer for it. If the file that was dropped onto the batch file above had the path C:\Users\My Documents\foobar.txt are you saying that within the batch file itself I should replace the space between "My" and "Documents" with quotation marks?

Comment: try `start excel.exe "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Compare.xlsm" /e "%~1"`

Comment: @Stephen - Well your method stops the old errors which were splitting up the file path on each space into substrings. Now when the batch file runs the full path gets passed into Excel which is what it was doing before but then as I am working with non Excel files i get an error saying that foobar.txt is an invalid file type. intesting when using an excel file on the batch file the program runs but then opens the excel file as a seperate workbook which is not wanted. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 1):

Try this (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
echo %~1
start "excel.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Compare.xlsm" /e/%1%
pause
```

Notice the quotes around "Excel.Exe" and the file path?

Another example

```
echo %~1
start "excel.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Blah Blah.xlsm" /e/%1%
pause
```

I am assuming that you are running the code from a `.Bat` file

Comment: For your first point about enclosing excel.exe within quotes. This does get rid of the errors however it also stops the information that is stored in %1% being passed to the the excel program. From within the VBA code accessing the commandline gives the path to the ECXEL.EXE and then a /dde switch and nothing else. Which is not what I need. I will edit my initial question to try and clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: Try "excel.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Compare.xlsm" "/e/%1%"

Comment: Unfortunately that hasnt worked either im afraid. If the excel.exe call is in quotes then I dont get the parameter within the vba code and if it is not the program still tries to open up the file referenced by the parameter.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you but I tried this and it opened the file in a new Excel Instance `start "excel.exe" "C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Documents\Sid Rout.xls" "/e/%1"`

Answer (score 0):

as Sid says, any paths that contain spaces must be quoted.

so to use a pth such as C:\My Documents\fubar.txt you would have this:

```
"C:\My Documents\fubar.txt"
```

and in your example:

echo

```
%~1
start excel.exe "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Compare.xlsm" /e/%1%
pause
```

EDIT:
When using a variable as the path, you need to include the quotes in the variable!

Comment: Hi, sorry think that is where i might be not getting my point across. It is not the location of the excel file (%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Compare.xlsm) where the issue is being thrown but the path that is stored in the %1 variable. I have tried surrounding the variable %1% in quotes i.e (/e/"%1%") yet the error still persists.

Comment: aha, my misunderstanding! In this case you need to include the quotes inside your variable

Comment: @Phillip, Might be being really stupid but what do you mean "include the quotes inside the variable? i have tried "%1%" as well as setting a whole new variable (set "testVar="%1"") but neither work as well.

Comment: you would have to include the ASCII code for the quototation. The code is 34, so you have to use `Chr(34) + value + Chr(34)`